# how to compare Datetime? to datetime in getter

Tags: c#, datetime

I have problem comparing properties in my class.I have property called IsActive and DateTime? DischargeDate. now we switch the of default value from null to 9999-12-12 00:00:00 and get return false even for DischargeDate = 9999-12-12 00:00:00

```
public DateTime? DischargeDate { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive
        {
            get
            {
                return this.DischargeDate.Equals("12/12/9999 12:00:00 AM");
                //return !this.DischargeDate.HasValue;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to check if the `DateTime?` actually has a value or is `null`, then you could construct a second `DateTime` to match them:

```
return this.DischargeDate != null
       && this.DischargeDate.Value == new DateTime(9999, 12, 12, 12, 0, 0);
```